# how to show some element taken by a file in a drop down menu

Tags: javascript, html, cytoscape.js

I have to block the flow of the code because i'm using cytoscape.js and once created the div cy i can't interact with non-cy element like a dropdown menu.
Here is my code:

```
<script>
    var list1 = [];
    var list2 = [];
    readTextFile("book.json", function(text){
        var data = JSON.parse(text);
        for (el in data.Concepts){
            var obj = data.Concepts[el];
            for(id in obj){
                list1.push(id);
            }
        }
        for (el in data.Roles){
            var obj = data.Roles[el];
            for(id in obj){
                list2.push(id);
            }
        }
    });
    document.write("<div id='cy'></div>");

    //CREATE CY 
    var cy = cytoscape({  
        container: document.getElementById('cy'),
        style: style
    });
<\script>
```

How can I show the element in `list1` and `list2` in a drop down menu and when the user chooses one element from `list1` and one from `list 2` as long as the flow continues?
Here is how `readTextFile` is made:

```
function readTextFile(file, callback) {
var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
rawFile.overrideMimeType("application/json");
rawFile.open("GET", file, false);
rawFile.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (rawFile.readyState === 4 && rawFile.status == "200") {
        callback(rawFile.responseText);
    }
}
rawFile.send(null);
}
```